Add Link Clicked Events to Link Labels in an Array
I have an array of x link labels that is generated and placed in a table that has 3 columns and n amount of rows, where x is columns * rows.
private void updateLayout(int numRows)
        {
            int eColCount = editTable.ColumnCount;                      //-- Edit Column Count (3)
            LinkLabel[] eLabels = new LinkLabel[numRows * eColCount];   //-- Array of edit labels to be populated

           for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
            {
                //-- Add new edit row --//
                editTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                editTable.RowCount = numRows - (numRows - row);

                for (int col = 0; col < eColCount; col++)
                {   
                    //-- Populate columns of new row --//
                    eLabels[row + col] = new LinkLabel();
                    popERow(eLabels, row, col); //-- Changes name text based on col index
                    editTable.Controls.Add(eLabels[row + col], col, row);
                }
            }
        }

I want to create a link clicked event method that launches a new form with a different string variable depending on the row. Here is the link clicked event for a defined label 'lblLinkEdit'.
private void lblLinkEdit_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Launch title edit form
            Cursor c = this.Cursor;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            frmTitleEdit titleEdit = new frmTitleEdit(commitName.Text);
            titleEdit.ShowDialog();

            this.Cursor = c;
        }

Is there a way to make a general method to handle these unique link labels in the array?

eLabels[row + col].LinkClicked += lblLinkEdit_LinkClicked; and change the function to use e.Link.

What would I change in the function to use e.Link?

MS has an example here: LinkLabel.Link Class
